# Is SSH a part of standard unix package?

Tags: unix, ssh

SSH - Secured shell runs on all Unix-like operating systems, but originally was it a part of standard Unix package?

Comment: Define "standard Unix package".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, it didn't come out until much later (1995) unix was from 1969.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell#Version_1.x

It was originally released as freeware:

> The goal of SSH was to replace the earlier rlogin, TELNET and rsh
>   protocols, which did not provide strong authentication nor guarantee
>   confidentiality. Ylönen released his implementation as freeware in
>   July 1995, and the tool quickly gained in popularity.

Comment: Not wrong, but...the "standard unix package" evolved steadily thoughout the 70's and 80's. Compare the system described in [Kernighan and Pike](http://www.amazon.com/Unix-Programming-Environment-Prentice-Hall-Software/dp/013937681X) to a "modern" unix.

Comment: You're right, but still it came out in 1995 ;)

Comment: And POSIX doesn't describe an `ssh` command.